# How to add text into a .csv data in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, csv

I want to add some text like `"Hi;Test;Pen"` into my .csv file.

I have used the [CSVImporter](https://github.com/Flinesoft/CSVImporter) to insert the text of the .csv into my Xcode project. Here is the code, I have used for it:

```
    guard let VokabelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: ResourceExample, ofType:"csv") else {
        debugPrint(ResourceExample + " not found")
        return
    }
    let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: VokabelPath, delimiter: ";")
    let importedRecords = importer.importRecords { $0 }
    for record in importedRecords {
        self.Vokabeln.insert(record, at: self.Vokabelzähler)
        self.Vokabelzähler += 1
    }
```

But for some reasons I want to

1. add something to the file
2. Change something in the file (e.g. in Line 4)
3. Delete the text in the file (e.g. `filetext = ""`

I have tried to use [this](http://www.justindoan.com/tutorials/2016/9/9/creating-and-exporting-a-csv-file-in-swift) Tutorial and I have made this code:

```
let fileName = "Tasks.csv"
let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
var csvText = "Test;Example;Apple;Pen\n"
do {
    try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch {
    print("Failed to create file")
    print("\(error)")
}


guard let VokabelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Tasks", ofType:"csv") else {
    debugPrint("Tasks not found")
    return
}
let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: VokabelPath, delimiter: ";")
let importedRecords = importer.importRecords { $0 }
for record in importedRecords {
    self.Vokabeln.insert(record, at: self.Vokabelzähler)
    self.Vokabelzähler += 1
    print(record)
}
```

but he prints only "Tasks not found". What is my mistake?

I hope you can help me,

Thank you.

EDIT:

The person who made the first answer has written, I can't save files in the bundle.
He has written to me I should use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`so I have updated my code and this works:

```
let DownloadPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
let VokabelPath = DownloadPath.appendingPathComponent("Tasks.csv")
let InhaltData = Inhalt.data(using: .utf8)
print(VokabelPath)

FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: VokabelPath, contents: InhaltData, attributes: nil)

let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(path: VokabelPath, delimiter: ";")
let importedRecords = importer.importRecords { $0 }
for record in importedRecords {
    self.Vokabeln.insert(record, at: self.Vokabelzähler)
    self.Vokabelzähler += 1
}
```

But I have one further question:
I hav some datas in my Xcode project and I can get them with `Bundle.main`. But I want to use only one function, so is it possible, to get them with `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to change a file, you would need to import the data in, make the necessary changes to the data and then write the data back to the same file, overwriting the previous content. That is how you would make changes generally - you don't make changes directly to the file.

Does that make sense?

If it does, then you could easily modify the tutorial you pointed to (the one for creating and exporting CSV) and write back the data that you read from the original file after you make the modifications.

As for your question about not wanting to use a library, you can always write your own CSV parser. It is not very difficult since all you have to do is read the text from the file a line at a time and then separate out the values by comma. A simple parser is straightforward but allowing for more complicated cases could take a bit more effort. It would all depend on your use-cases and the type of data you'd be handling. The easiest way still would be to use your importing library and then output via custom code.

Regarding your additional questions, if the following code fails:

```
guard let VokabelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Tasks", ofType:"csv") else {
    debugPrint("Tasks not found")
    return
}
```

Then there is either an issue with the file name (or extension) or you have not included the file as part of your Resources. The above code simply gets the path for a given file in your Resources.

The above code is different from what I was talking about with regards to `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` - that was for **writing** a file from your app. What I meant was that you could not write a file back to your Resources - instead, you would have to write the modified file to your Documents folder. Hope that clarifies things :)

Comment: I have tried this before but if I want to write a new file with the part `guard let VokabelPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: ResourceExample, ofType:"csv") else {
        debugPrint(ResourceExample + " not found")
        return
    }`I only get an error.

Comment: You can't write a new file to the Bundle path :) The bundle is basically your application file - you cannot modify that. Instead, you have to save the new file to a path in your sandboxed documents folder on your device. You can get the documents folder via the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` method and then append the file name for the new CSV file you want to create to it ...

Comment: I don't know how to make this. I have edited my question, I hope you can say me now, what I have done wrong and an example of how it should work :). Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand the differences between the bundles and the different folders in `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` because I am new in this (datas in swift), so I have the question why I can use Bundle for datas I have saved in the Xcode project but not for datas I make new. Is it possible to use `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` for datas I have saved? I have updated the question again.

Comment: I've updated my answer with additional information. Hopefully, that helps :)